# Como atualizar $scope.items após execução de push?

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

JavaScript:

```
var app = angular.module('app', []);
    app.controller('controlador', function($scope, $http) {
    $scope.user = {};
    $scope.items = [];
    var sum = 1;
    $scope.submitForm = function() {

        $http({
          method  : 'POST',
          url     : 'clone.php',
          data    : $scope.items,
          headers : {'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'} 
         })
          .success(function(data) {
            if (data.errors) {
              $scope.erroNome = data.errors.nome;
              $scope.erroEmail = data.errors.email;
            } else {
              $scope.mensagem = data.mensagem;
            }
          });
    };

    $scope.addItem = function (user){
            $scope.items.push({
                nome: $("input[name='nome']").val(),
                email: $("input[name='email']").val(),
                soma: sum++
            });
          user.nome = '';
          user.email = '';  
    };
});
```

HTML:

```
<body ng-app="app" ng-controller="controlador">

<form ng-submit="submitForm()">
    <label>Nome: </label><input type="text" name="nome" ng-model="user.nome">
    <span ng-show="erroNome">{{erroNome}}</span>
    <label>E-mail: </label><input type="text" name="email" ng-model="user.email">
    <span ng-show="erroEmail">{{erroEmail}}</span>
    <input type="button" value="Adicionar" ng-click="addItem(user)" />
    <input type="submit" value="Enviar" /><br /><br />

</form>
<br />

<div ng-repeat="item in items">
ID: {{item.soma}}<br />
Nome: {{item.nome}}<br /><label>Novo nome: </label><input type="text" name="nome"><br />
E-mail: {{item.email}}<br /><label>Novo e-mail: <input type="text" name="email"><br /><br />
<input type="button" value="Atualizar" />
<hr />
</div>

</body>
```

Comment: Utilize `$scope.$apply()` após o push.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Acredito que sua função seja para o botão, "Atualizar", então aqui vai uma sugestão:

Criei a função `updateItem`, que recebe como argumento a atualização e o respectivo item a ser modificado. Ela percorre o `$scope.items` e verifica qual dos items do array vai ser atualizado, ao verificar ela aplica apenas a atualização necessária (ou nome, ou email ou os dois):

```
  $scope.updateItem = function(update, old) {
    $scope.items.forEach(function(item, i){
      if(item.nome == old.nome && item.email == old.email){
        if(update.nome) item.nome = update.nome
        if(update.email) item.email = update.email
      }
    });
    item.nome = '';
    item.email = '';
  };
```

E modifiquei seu HTML da seguinte forma:

Agora há uma variável no escopo, chamada `update` que contem a atualização e será ela a ser passada na função `updateItems`:

```
<div ng-repeat="item in items">
    ID: {{item.soma}}
    <br /> Nome: {{item.nome}}
    <br />
    <label>Novo nome: </label>
    <input type="text" name="nome" ng-model="update.nome">
    <br /> E-mail: {{item.email}}
    <br />
    <label>Novo e-mail:
      <input type="text" name="email" ng-model="update.email"> </label>
    <br />
    <br />
    <input type="button" value="Atualizar" ng-click="updateItem(update, item)" />
    <hr />
</div>
```

A função `updateItem` está no `ng-click` do botão `Atualizar`.

## DEMO

```js
var app = angular.module('app', []);
app.controller('MyCtrl', function($scope, $http) {
  $scope.user = {};
  $scope.items = [];
  var sum = 1;

  $scope.addItem = function(user) {
    $scope.items.push({
      nome: user.nome,
      email: user.email,
      soma: sum++
    });
    user.nome = '';
    user.email = '';
  };
  $scope.updateItem = function(update, old) {
    $scope.items.forEach(function(item, i) {
      if (item.nome == old.nome && item.email == old.email) {
        if (update.nome) item.nome = update.nome
        if (update.email) item.email = update.email
      }
    });
    update.nome = '';
    update.email = '';
  };
});
```

```css
div {
  margin: 10px;
  padding: 10px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="app" ng-controller="MyCtrl">
  <form ng-submit="submitForm()">
    <label>Nome: </label>
    <input type="text" name="nome" ng-model="user.nome">
    <br>
    <span ng-show="erroNome">{{erroNome}}</span>
    <label>E-mail: </label>
    <input type="text" name="email" ng-model="user.email">
    <span ng-show="erroEmail">{{erroEmail}}</span>
    <br>
    <input type="button" value="Adicionar" ng-click="addItem(user)" />
    <input type="submit" value="Enviar" />
    <br />
    <br />

  </form>
  <br />

  <div ng-repeat="item in items">
    ID: {{item.soma}}
    <br /> Nome: {{item.nome}}
    <br />
    <label>Novo nome: </label>
    <input type="text" name="nome" ng-model="update.nome">
    <br /> E-mail: {{item.email}}
    <br />
    <label>Novo e-mail:
      <input type="text" name="email" ng-model="update.email"> </label>
    <br />
    <br />
    <input type="button" value="Atualizar" ng-click="updateItem(update, item)" />
    <hr />
  </div>
```

Comment: Muito obrigado @samirbraga, era isso o que estava precisando! Contudo, como faço para atualizar vários itens, sem que o código fique enorme e cheio de condicionais?

Comment: @luccasrodrigo, imagino que desse modo já seja possível atualizar vários itens, está tendo problemas?

Comment: podemos ir para o chat?

Comment: @luccasrodrigo, podemos

Comment: Chat http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/51050/como-atualizar-scope-items-apos-execucao-de-push

Answer (score 1):

```
$scope.addItem = function () {
    $scope.items.push({
        nome: $scope.user.nome,
        email: $scope.user.email,
        soma: sum++
    });

    $scope.user.nome = '';
    $scope.user.email = '';  
};
```

Você não precisa passar o argumento direto no atributo: `ng-click="addItem(user)"` se pode recuperar os dados pelo `$scope`.

Além disso você está tentando atualizar os dados assim: `user.nome = ""` ao invés de `$scope.user.nome = ""`

---

Erro que está acusando no seu código:

> TypeError: Cannot set property 'nome' of undefined